# How to Fill Arrays with GenFu

Tags: c#, genfu

Using GenFu on a class with an Array doesn't work, here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
public class Row
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Cell = new string[5];
} 

public void Test() {
//This line works with a defined property
GenFu.GenFu.Configure<Row>().Fill(r => r.Id, () => { return i++; });

//This line fails (Object Ref not set to an instance)
GenFu.GenFu.Configure<Row>().Fill(r => r.Cell[0], () => { return "Row " + i++.ToString(); });
}
```

How can I populate the Cells when they're an Array, or is this a limitation of the Library?